# Can't connect to Tomcat even though it's running

Tags: tomcat

I started the tomcat, but failed to connect it, are there some ideas to debug with? Thanks in advance!

```
$ service tomcat status
Tomcat is running with pid: 4648

$ netstat -tnlp
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:111             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8081          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3165/python3        
tcp        0      0 192.168.122.1:53        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1589/dnsmasq        
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1150/sshd           
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:631           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      978/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::3306                 :::*                    LISTEN      1105/mysqld         
tcp6       0      0 :::111                  :::*                    LISTEN      1/systemd           
tcp6       0      0 ::1:631                 :::*                    LISTEN      978/cupsd           
tcp6       0      0 :::33060                :::*                    LISTEN      1105/mysqld         
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8005          :::*                    LISTEN      4648/java 

$ ps axu | grep tomcat
www         4648  0.2  7.9 3009628 139932 ?      Sl   02:17   0:06 /usr/java/jdk-16/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/usr/local/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom -server -Xms256m -Xmx496m -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -Dorg.apache.catalina.security.SecurityListener.UMASK=0027 -Dignore.endorsed.dirs= -classpath /usr/local/tomcat/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -Dcatalina.base=/usr/local/tomcat -Dcatalina.home=/usr/local/tomcat -Djava.io.tmpdir=/usr/local/tomcat/temp org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
root        7202  0.0  0.0  12136  1044 pts/1    R+   02:54   0:00 grep --color=auto tomcat
```

Comment: Look at the logs, port 8080 is not opened.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, LMC!

I checked the `catalina.out`, and found the latest error,

```
18-Jul-2021 02:17:59.786 SEVERE [Catalina-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.open Failed to open access log file [/usr/local/tomcat/logs/localhost_access_log.2021-07-18.txt] Note: running as user [www]
```

Does that mean that I used a wrong account to start the tomcat? Or is the file ownership wrong?

Comment: Directory does not exists or you are running tomcat as non-root user. If runiing under our user, point logs to under your user home.

Comment: Thank you, LMC! I've found the root cause according to your guidance!